# Error inserting UUID's into Cassandra 1.2 using JDBC driver

Tags: jdbc, cassandra

I get an exception when trying to insert a UUID into Cassandra 1.2 using the JDBC driver. Here's the code:

```
UUID uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID();
PreparedStatement statement = c.prepareStatement("insert into tree (tree_id) values (?)");
statement.setObject(1, uuid);
statement.execute();
```

Here's the exception I get:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: encountered object of class: class java.util.UUID, but only 'String' is supported to map to the various VARCHAR types
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.HandleObjects.makeBadMapping(HandleObjects.java:124)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.HandleObjects.makeBytes(HandleObjects.java:391)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraPreparedStatement.setObject(CassandraPreparedStatement.java:351)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraPreparedStatement.setObject(CassandraPreparedStatement.java:338)
        at CassandraTest.main(CassandraTest.java:26)
```

and here is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE browse.tree (tree_id UUID PRIMARY KEY, activation_time TIMESTAMP, tree_lock_id INT, sql_publication_id INT);
```

Kind of weird that it thinks my UUID field is a VARCHAR. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

UUID is not part of the java.sql.Types specification.  My reading then is that the correct behavior would be for the driver to throw a SQLException.  Alternatively, it could bend the rules a bit and accept it anyway.

As a workaround, the string representation of the uuid should work, but I'd really recommend using the [native CQL driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) instead of JDBC.  You won't have any of these spec mismatches, and it does a much better job of dealing with things like failover and load-balancing.

Comment: Thanks, but String representation doesn't work either. Says it needs to be exactly 16 bytes. Byte[] doesn't work either (same error as UUID). UUID's are one of the most important types, I have a hard time seeing how that could be completely broken. I'll look into the native CQL driver.

Comment: As said by Jonathan try using native CQL Driver. Further for generating UUID values see cassandra FAQ, how to generate UUID, quite a good description given there

Answer (score 0):

you can use pattern introspection to resolve this limitation.

My table:

CREATE TABLE TEST_KEY (pk uuid, text varchar, primary key(pk));

My introspection:

```
package org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.UUID;


public class CassandraPS {

   private PreparedStatement ps;

   public CassandraPS(PreparedStatement ps) {
      this.ps = ps;
   }

   public void setUUID(int parameterIndex, UUID uuid) throws SQLException {
      CassandraPreparedStatement psCas = (CassandraPreparedStatement) ps;
      psCas.setObject(parameterIndex, JdbcUUID.instance.decompose(uuid).array(),
      Types.LONGVARBINARY);
   }
}
```

My DAO:

```
....... DAO ..........
public void insert(UUID pk, String text) throws SQLException {
   String cql = "insert into my_ks.test_key(pk, text) values(?,?)";
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
   try {
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(cql);
      new CassandraPS(ps).setUUID(1, pk);
      ps.setString(2, text);
      ps.executeUpdate();
    } finally {
       if (ps != null) {
         ps.close();
    }
  }
}
...
```

My driver:
cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5.jar

Gilberto Vieira da Silva

Answer (score 0):

Gilberto is right. use this funciton:

```
public static byte[] uuid2ByteArray(java.util.UUID uuid) {
    long msb = uuid.getMostSignificantBits();
    long lsb = uuid.getLeastSignificantBits();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16];

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        buffer[i] = (byte) (msb >>> 8 * (7 - i));
    }
    for (int i = 8; i < 16; i++) {
        buffer[i] = (byte) (lsb >>> 8 * (7 - i));
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

convert uuid to byte array, and then ps.setObject( index,  byte_array, Types.VARBINARY) also works